# Dynamically generated script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a contenteditable div where you type javascript which gets outputted into an empty script tag.

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="script-generator"></div>
<div id="save-script">Save</div>

<script type="text/shorthand" id="script">
</script>
```

So you write your script in the div, click save and I have some JS which gets the html of the contenteditable div and adds it to an empty script tag.

```
$('#save-script').click(function() {
  var script = $('#script-generator').html();
  $('#script').html(script);
});
```

So far this works. But the generated script has no effect. The browser must not recognise the script because it wasn't there on page load? How do I make the script take effect without reloading the page?

Note: The type/shortand on the script is because I'm using a [plugin which converts shortand words](https://github.com/splatcollision/shorthand.js) into actual Javascript. So the user would just need to write shorthand into the contenteditable div, and the plugin would convert that to JS. This might be adding to the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it works to modify an existing `<script>` element. If you want the script to be executed you need to add a *new* element.

```
$('#save-script').click(function() {
    var script = $('#script-generator').html();
    $("#script").text(script);
    ShortHand.parseScripts();
});
```

Comment: Still can't get it working mate. I tried changing the script type to Javascript and writing a regular JS click function instead of the shorthand plugin function but that didn't work either.

Comment: Ok wait. It's outputting some random div tags into the JS. <div>$('#show').click(function() {</div><div>&nbsp; $('#pink_box').show();</div><div>});</div>

Comment: Maybe use `.text()` to get the content of `#script-generator`.

Comment: use .text() if it's pure text with no HTML tags, else .html()

Comment: The user is typing Javascript into the DIV. The issue seems to be that `.html()` returns entities instead of the raw text.

Comment: Why is that confusing? Is there a better way to do it? If there is I'd love to know. Actually, the user enters natural language into the div. This is then converted to JS by the plugin. The goal is to allow users to build JS interactions quickly.

Comment: I got it working anyway guys. I changed both all instances of "html" to "text" and it works now. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I wonder if the shorthand is getting in the way. I don't know how the plugin works, but maybe it doesn't process dynamically added elements.

Comment: Yeah, I can get it working with plain JS. It doesn't work with shorthand though.

Comment: I checked the source code, and shorthand normally only translates scripts when the DOM is loaded. It looks like calling `Shorthand.parseScripts()` will execute all the shorthand scripts on the page. But this will re-execute previous scripts. I don't see a way to process just the new script element.

Comment: I should only have one shorthand script on the page though, so it sounds like that might work. Where do I put that parseScripts line?

Comment: Every time the user clicks on `#save-script` you'll create another shorthand script. Unless you delete the old one when you add the new one.

Comment: Yeah, I'm planning to delete the old one and replace it with the new one.

Comment: Where should I put that Shorthand.parseScripts() line? I tried adding it to the click function but I'm not sure if it does anything?

Comment: Console says "Shorthand is not defined"

Comment: It works! She's so sexy, thanks for all the help mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Correct - you need to create the script tag to have it execute after load.

```
$('head').append($('<script />', {html: script}));
```

...which means you can remove your empty script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have set up a test that's similar to what you have been looking for. Take a look and see if that helps.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p3V8t/)
Test code:

```
<div id="script" style="display:none">
    alert(4+4);
</div>
<input id="sLoad" type="button" value="Load/Execute Script" />

$('#sLoad').click(function(){
    //You may want to append to the head
    $('<script/>').append( $('#script').html() ).appendTo('#script');

});
```

Comment: I actually have it working now with regular JS functions. I can't get it working with the shorthand.js plugin for some reason though.